# Retrieve average CPU-workload with Get-Counter

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to retrieve the average CPU-workload with PowerShell.

At the beginning of a script, I want to start the tracking of the CPU-workload and when it is finished I want to get the average CPU-workload between. (like 71.5%)

After a research on the web I started using a (PowerShell-)"job" for this purpose, but I was not able to get it working. This is the reduced code I have till now:

```
$JobObject = Start-Job -Name "MyJob" -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -Continuous
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$Result = Receive-Job -Job $JobObject
```

I was not able to simple get the average of captured values.
How to get this working?

Thank you

Edit: It is not a requirement by me to make use of jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the average separately after receiving the job:

```
$JobObject = Start-Job -Name "MyJob" -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -Continuous
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$Result = Receive-Job -Job $JobObject

$Result.Readings | Foreach-Object { ($_ -split ':')[-1].Trim() } |
    Measure-Object -Average | Select-Object @{n='Average';e={"{0:f2}" -f $_.Average}}
```

**Explanation:**

`$Result.Readings` contains all of your sample readings in string format. You will have to parse the CPU percentage from that.

`-split ':'` creates an array by separating the input string by `:`. The resulting array contains as many elements as there are `:` characters. Since we only want the number after the final `:`, index `[-1]` is used.

The format operator `-f` requires a specific syntax. The `{0}` syntax represents a placeholder for the first object after the `-f`. `{1}` would represent the second object. A trivial example would be `"{0}=={1}" -f $var1,$var2`, which will output string versions of `$var1` and `$var2` separated by a `==`. The `{0:f2}` tells PowerShell to format the first object (indicated by `0`) using a fixed decimal (indicated by `f`) to two places (indicated by `2`).

Comment: It is not the first time you helped me. You answers are high-quality. Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice script. Thank you.
I've tried it with -SampleInterval 10 -MaxSamples 6. If I've got this right, that should take 60 seconds to process, plus the 5 seconds of sleep for 65 seconds. But when I run the script, it completes in about 5 seconds. Am I missing something?